# What is the global variabel in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Instead of writing

```
var global = window
```

for the browser I want my code to be able to work in a node enviornment as well.

Something like

```
var global = window || node_global
```

What is `node_global`?

Did not see anything obvious here:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=global+node+variable

or here

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=node+global+variable++&*

**Code**

```
// set your global variable with glob
Pub.globalManager = (function () {
    var global = window;
    var glob = "$A";
    var previous = global[glob];
    var pub = {};

    // package name is set here
    // this is the first component
    Pub.pack = {
        utility: true
    };

    // set the global property
    pub.release = function () {
        global[glob] = Pub.extendSafe(global[glob] || {}, Pub);
    };

    // return the global property back to its original owner
    pub.noConflict = function () {
        var temp = global[glob];
        global[glob] = previous;
        return temp;
    };
    return pub;
}());
```

Comment: It's `global`. Just `global`.

Comment: Why would you be writing `var global = window` in the browser at all?

Comment: The fun part of this code is that it hides node's global `global` behind this local `global`.

Comment: If you can write your code without writing to global at all, I suggest you do so. The module system is usually a better way to access your other code.

Comment: ... seriously ... it's `global` ... where is this in the node docs?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Comment: So each module has it's own global variable ?

Comment: @zen I believe `global` is shared process-wide. If you hide it with your own local called `global`, you will need a different way to access it though.

Answer (score 1):

[There is already a TC39 proposal to add `global` to ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global). Alternatively you can use this npm module [system.global](https://www.npmjs.com/package/system.global).

And it's [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global/blob/master/polyfill.js):

```
'use strict';
(function (global) {
    if (!global.global) {
        if (Object.defineProperty) {
            Object.defineProperty(global, 'global', {
                configurable: true,
                enumerable: false,
                value: global,
                writable: true
            });
        } else {
            global.global = global;
        }
    }
})(typeof this === 'object' ? this : Function('return this')())
```